# Pattern matching with Chinese characters (encoded in UTF-8) in Java

Tags: java, string, cjk

I need to check whether a Chinese province is contained within an address in Chinese.

I am able to read and write Chinese characters easily.

I tried to use the indexOf() method of String to check whether a province (e.g. 广东) is contained within an address (中国 广东). However, this always returns -1.

When I try to check for numbers (e.g. whether 103 is contained within 9910399) it works fine.

Do I need to do something different to handle UTF-8 string matching?
Thanks.
Matt

Comment: Java `String` is always UTF-16 internally, so whichever problems you have are not UTF-8 related. Are you 100% sure that the characters in the string are the exact same ones you're searching for? Check with `System.out.println((int)s.charAt(i))` on both sides.

Comment: Your example works for me, have you checked that your .java file saves with the right encoding?

Answer (score 2):

I have just tried your example and although I do not have Chineese fonts on my system, so the characters are not displayed correctly indexOf() works fine for me.

So, check encoding of your source files (*.java). For example if you are using eclipse check it under Window/Preferences/General/Workspace/Text file Encoding. I am using UTF-8.

The second think is the encoding used by java compiler. In case of eclipse  you do not have to say anything. I think that for `javac` you probably should explicitely set encoding using `-encoding`. Otherwise the default OS encoding will be probably used.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks a lot! I realized I was not specific enough. You are absolutely right - the above example works fine if I just use the strings directly. The problem happens when I read these strings from a file. I printed out the actual characters and I noticed that ASCII 34 was showing up before the Unicode characters.

Comment: It looks I am not having a Chinese-specific problem - its a file reading problem. I have 2 files - province and address. I had the character A in province and AB in address. When I read them using readline() and print them out I see the following printed out (1) For province while only had A - 34:65:34 (2) for addreseses which only had AB - 34:65:66:34 Not sure what I should do to make sure that province is matched to address, or A matches to AB

Comment: @Matt - AlexR is correct; look at the relevant I/O methods that take encoding (String IDs or Charset) inputs. You must always decode textual data inputs as appropriate (including Java source files). See [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html) for a basic primer. See [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/09/java-character-inspector-application.html) for a primitive app that can help diagnose problems.